# Starting Child workflow from Signal in Temporal

Tags: java, temporal-workflow

I have a set up which creates one parent workflow and then creates a child workflow from it.

Now I have a requirement to reset the child workflow on certain action(let us say an event). By the time action being performed , child workflow can be active or in completed state.

Solution I have done.

I am signalling Parent workflow on the event and in the signal , I am terminating child workflow if exists and re-creating the new child workflow . I have tested it seems working fine… Want to know if this is correct approach or is these any better way to solve the problem…

I am using java-sdk

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are invoking activity from signal handler that terminates the workflow execution (guess you check if it exists first too?).

Think would be better to start child execution in cancellation scope and on signal cancel the scope (cancel child if running allowing it to do cleanup if needed) and then invoke it again if needed. See sample [here](https://github.com/temporalio/samples-java/blob/main/core/src/main/java/io/temporal/samples/hello/HelloCancellationScope.java) if that helps.